# Display video on homepage for users who have not logged in

Tags: users, login, videos, genesis-theme-framework

I am trying to figure out how to display a video on the homepage for users who have not logged in using the `functions.php` file. I am using a Genesis theme.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you already know how to get your popup video working, and you want to know how to make sure only people who aren't logged in see the video. You can add this to your template file (footer.php is probably best):

```
<?php
  if (is_front_page() && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    //video popup content
  }
?>
```

- [WP: is_user_logged_in() »](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)
- [WP: is_front_page() »](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try to add above code with youtube video link with no luck.

if (is_front_page() && !is_user_logged_in()) {?>